# Vertically aligning center image and label inside a common div in a same horizontal line in any browser

Tags: html, css

I have this following html code in my page:

```
<div class="container"> (Can't have static height)
    <img></img> (Has variable height)
    <label></label> (Has variable length)
</div>
```

I want to align both of them in a same line vertically applied in any browser. If it's possible by a standard way how should I work?
I have searched and read a lot of articles to fix this problem but it wasn't worked.

Edit: The "container" div in this case isn't the  main container div in page and it has 3 other parents above itself that they have no effect on position of it.

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flex by adding **:before** and **:after** with `flex:1` which will make the image/text always in the center. Then you can use flex again for image and text to make them aligned in the same line like this:

*Go full page to see the result better*

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.page:before,
.page:after {
  content: " ";
  flex: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/">
    <label>text</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfifI. But I want vertically align center this two content in a same horizontal line not vertical line. Also I want it work in every browser.

Comment: @MiladRashidi so you mean you want them side by side ?

Comment: @MiladRashidi ok i updated my answer to make them in one line. Is it ok like this ?

Comment: Yes I want that exactly if you can show me how should I do that please.

Comment: @MiladRashidi also this solution is supported by almost all modern brwoser like you read here https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. I think you will face issue only with IE9 and lower

Comment: Nope. You fixed the height of the container div and I won't do that in my page because of the height of my image and the length of my label are dynamic.

Comment: @MiladRashidi no, i fixed the height to simply make it full height and take all the page space. I didn't fix the height of image

Comment: @MiladRashidi the container here is like the body of the page or the container that take all the height of the page, then you have content which the container of image+text

Comment: You mean if I use you style rules without .container { height: 100vh; } I should fix my problem?

Comment: @MiladRashidi it will depend on your site but the container here is similar to all the page, am not sure how your page look. Can you show me ?

Comment: @MiladRashidi i updated again for more clarity but keeping the container as it is and by adding another div that behave like the page

Comment: I tried exactly what you said in your solution and I removed extra style codes from my case but the new problem generated and it's: the content div according to your solution not in the center of container div. Also I should say the container div in my page isn't the main container of page. I will update my question to increase clarity.

Comment: @MiladRashidi are you able to show me or share link with me ? i will tell you want you should update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159309/discussion-between-milad-rashidi-and-temani-afif).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `text-align`, `display` and `line-height` like the following:

```
<style>
    .container{
      text-align: center;
    }
    .container label{
      display: block;      
      line-height: 0; /*To stick the label under the bottom edge of the image*/
    }
    .container img{
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
```

Checkout this [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/rotarucosu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Thank you @SaidbakR. I tried your solution but it didn't worked. Also I should say I want align the image and label in a same line horizontally and I won't place the label in corner of image.

Comment: Good luck, however, " *them in a same line vertically applied* " that I have understood from your question. Could you tell me the browser that you have tested the demo using it? @MiladRashidi